# Why won't the rectangle appear or move

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to get a rectangle to fire at the apposing sprite and defeat it when it hits. As far as i'm concerned the rectangle should be created when I click space and fired at a speed of 5 pixel's `move.ip[5,0]` but I can not see the rectangle. What is wrong with my code and why can't i see the rectangle.

My Code:

```
MESH = ((playerRect.topright[1] + 1), (playerRect.topright[1] + 1), (playerRect.centery - 10), (playerRect.centery + 10))
shootRect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, MESH)

def baddieHasHitShoot():
    if baddieRect.colliderect(shootRect):
        return True
    return False

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == ord(' '):
                shootRect()
                move.ip[5, 0]

    if baddieHasHitShoot():
        if score > topScore:
            score = topscore
            break
```

The Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 105, in <module>
    shootRect()
TypeError: 'pygame.Rect' object is not callable
```

Comment: Not sure if it will fix it but you need to  remove the parens from `shootRect() -> shootRect`, your error is from trying to call `shootRect()` which is a `pygame.Rect` object and that is not callable.

Comment: Now it has another error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***.py", line 106, in <module>
    move.ip[5, 0]
NameError: name 'move' is not defined`

Comment: move is not defined as the error suggests, what is move supposed to be? Also probably best to not use `shootRect` everywhere.

Comment: if you remove variables from `baddieHasHitShoot()` you will have problem with `.colliderect(shootRect)`

Comment: because `.colliderect()` expects `pygame.Rect()` but now `shootRect` is function name :)

Comment: as for me you shouldn't use `shootRect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, MESH)`

Comment: I did not mean totally remove the args, I just meant don't use  the same variable name for everything

Comment: @user3831295 see my answer again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shootRect` inside `baddieHasHitShoot` is local variable and has nothing to do with external `shootRect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, MESH)`

`shootRect` inside `baddieHasHitShoot` is not function so you can execute it `shootRect()`.

Better use in functions different names to not be suprised.

Inside `baddieHasHitShoot` you probably have to use

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, shootRect)
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

as for me I wouldn't use something like this

```
shootRect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, MESH)
```

but rather

```
shoot_rect = MESH
shoot_color = WHITE
```

and then use this

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, shoot_color, shoot_rect)
```

in places where I need it.

---

**EDIT 2:**

I thing you need:

```
MESH = ((playerRect.topright[1] + 1), (playerRect.topright[1] + 1), (playerRect.centery - 10), (playerRect.centery + 10))

shootRect = pygame.Rect( MESH[0], MESH[1], MESH[2], MESH[3] )

shooted = False

#-----------

def baddieHasHitShoot(b_rect, s_rect):
    if b_rect.colliderect(s_rect):
        return True
    return False

#-----------

if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == ord(' '):
        # pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, shootRect) # see below
        shooted = True

#-----------

if baddieHasHitShoot( baddieRect, shootRect):
    if score > topScore:
        score = topscore
        break
```

---

**EDIT 3:**

`pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, shootRect)` has to be after bliting background and before `display.update()`

```
    screen.blit(background, backgroundRect)
    screen.blit(playerImage, playerRect)
    screen.blit(baddieImage, baddieRect)

    if shooted:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, shootRect)
        shootRect.move_ip( (5, 0) )

    drawText('Score: %s' % (score), font, screen, 200, 0)
    drawText('Top Score: %s' % (topScore), font, screen, 195, 40)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score -1):

your call to `shootRect` is missing parenthesses. it should be `shootRect()`
thats assuming it's a function your trying to call.

if its just a variable you need to do something with it.

Comment: there is different problem with that `shootRect` - there are two `shootRect` - global and local :)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `there are two shootRect - global and local`